# Bash: how to enter a subdirectory that's most recently modified?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I know I can find a directory that's most recently modified by doing ls -ltr, but the last modified item might be a file, not a directory. Secondly I still have to type the directory name. My directory name is like a hash code, which is not really readable and it's quite painful to type each time.

Any easy one-liner to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd "$(ls -dt */ | head -1)"
```

Save this as an alias in `~/.bashrc`, e.g.

```
alias lcd='cd -- "$(ls -dt -- */ | head -1)"'
```

and now `lcd` in any directory will change to the most recently changed directory in the current directory.

Comment: Keep in mind that the timestamp ls is checking here doesn't recurse - ie, it does not find the most recently modified file anywhere in the tree. It only measures *direct* changes to that directory.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the error `-bash: cd: mydir/: No such file or directory` where `mydir` is the last modified directory. It seems to find the right directory but something is causing `cd` to fail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Adding this function to my `~/.bashrc` works for me

```
function lcd(){
cd $(ls -v1td --color=never */ | head -1)
}
```

If I try to define it as an alias, the expression gets evaluated once when the shell starts and always tries to cd to the same subdirectory in my home directory. Without the `--color=never` statement, I get the error `-bash: cd: mydir/: No such file or directory` mentioned in another comment.